# Is legal aid for criminal defence usually means tested?

Tags: united-kingdom, legal-aid

Allison was charged with a crime, and would like to fund her defence through legal aid. What would make her eligible?

Answer (score 2):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

[Legal aid is means tested based on assets and income](https://www.justice.gc.ca/eng/rp-pr/csj-sjc/jsp-sjp/rr03_la5-rr03_aj5/p01.html#header5).

If a person is denied legal aid, [a court may still order the government to fund defence counsel for serious and complex charges](https://legalaid.bc.ca/publications/pub/if-you-cant-get-legal-aid-your-criminal-trial).

Answer (score 0):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

Legal aid will give advice for free but representation is [means tested](https://www.legalaid.nsw.gov.au/ways-to-get-help/apply-for-legal-aid/means-test-indicator).

There are also private, charitable community legal assistance organisations that have their own criteria.